# jQuery animation only rendering text word by word

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome, jquery-animate

I'm not sure if this is more of a jQuery, CSS, or browser-related question, but this is what I've been wondering:

In the jsfiddle/code below, the animation starts off by displaying the word "this" pixel by pixel in the animation, but after that it does not show the text of the expanding span until the entire word is rendered; why is that?  Also, can it be changed to be like the animation of the first word?

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XKVng/

```
<html>
<style type="text/css">
#mask {
  z-index: 3;
  position: absolute;
  float: right;
  width: 0;
  height: 20px;
  color: white;
  margin:0;
  background-color: black;
}
#text {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  width: 200px;
  margin:0;
  float: right;
  height: 20px;
}

</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("document").ready(function() {
  var width = $("#text").width();
  var opts = { "easing" : "linear", "duration" : 4000, "queue" : false};
  $("#mask").animate({"width" : width}, opts);
  $("#maskBg").animate({"width" : width}, opts);
});



</script>
<body>
<span id="mask">this is some text to demo with</span>
<span id="text">this is some text to demo with</span>
</body>
</html>
```

The browser I've been using is Chromium Version 31.0.1650.63 Built on Debian 7.2, running on Debian 7.3 (238485).

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the words wrap to a new line during the animation. You could solve this by adding [`white-space:nowrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) to the `#mask` element, thus preventing this default behavior from occurring.

[**UPDATED EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/4MJZb/)

```
#mask {
    z-index: 3;
    position: absolute;
    float: right;
    width: 0;
    height: 20px;
    color: white;
    margin:0;
    background-color: black;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```